# Why is the device viewer different than the simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have constraints for my iOS application and I run the simulator an this is how it runs on the iPad Pro simulator...
[9.7 inch iPad Pro Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDV6z.png)

And then when I view the device in Xcode as a 9.7 inch iPad Pro, it looks exactly how I want it to. I cleaned the build and restarted Xcode and the simulator but each show a different result. 
[View as 9.7 inch device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnHOt.png)

So if I was to run the program on an actual 9.7 inch iPad, which one would it run like?

Comment: What is the issue???

Comment: when you run in your device it would look like similar to how you get in simulator

Comment: The issue it the way they look, they are both apparently 9.7 inch displays, but they look different on both, how would it look if I actually ran the program on the actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not fullscreen on the iPad, because it is not a Universal app. It is running in the iPhone mode and just stretched.

To make your app a Universal app, select the Project in Xcode, select the **Target**, go to the **General** Tab and change **Devices** from `iPhone` to `Universal`.

Without any changes the app on a real device would look like the app running in the simulator.

Comment: Ok thank you! so would apple accept it if i submitted it as an app? Like would it work fine if they tested it on the iPad?

Comment: It is allowed to submit an iPhone only app (ie. a app that is not a universal app). If there are no other issues, than Apple should accept it.